# Magento display sub's sub category in layered navigation

Tags: category, layered-navigation, navigation

I have Category hierarchy as,

```
Root Category 
Category 1
    Category 1.1
        Category 1.1.1
        Category 1.1.2
        Category 1.1.3
    Category 1.2
        Category 1.2.1
        Category 1.2.2
        Category 1.2.3
    Category 1.3
Category 2
.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

**Question**
After Clicking first category (eg. Catergory 1). In left side layered Navigation, it dispays only it's sub category. Not sub's sub category.

Eg. I want this after Clicking Category 1 in layered navigation as,

```
Category 1.1
    Category 1.1.1
    Category 1.1.2
    Category 1.1.3

Category 1.2
    Category 1.2.1
    Category 1.2.2
    Category 1.2.3

Category 1.3
    Category 1.3.1
    Category 1.3.2
    Category 1.3.3
```

And after clicking Category 2,

```
Category 2.1
    Category 2.1.1
    Category 2.1.2
    Category 2.1.3

Category 2.2
    Category 2.2.1
    Category 2.2.2
    Category 2.2.3

Category 2.3
    Category 2.3.1
    Category 2.3.2
    Category 2.3.3
```

and so on ....

How can i achieve this .. please help .. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This happens in the core Magento code. In the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category` when it gets all the categories to select it limits the categories to only direct children.

It starts with the function `_getItemsData` but the limitation happens in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getChildrenCategories` when it filters all the categories by children ids.

```
$collection = $this->_getChildrenCategoriesBase($category);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
    ->load();
```

Here the function `$category->getChildren` only returns direct children and not all children.

Try updating the code to use `getAllChildren` instead as this should recursively get the category ids.